# Android - Detect network busy state for outgoing calls

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop android application, to report network areas which have problem in network resources.

so I want to detect when an outgoing call can not be completed, and the handset receives "Network busy" message from network provider.

How can I do that? even by parsing logs?